# How do you evaluate $\bigcup\bigcup S$ if $S = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do you evaluate $\bigcup\bigcup S$ if $S = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$? I understand that $\bigcup S = \{a,b\}$ but how can I find $\bigcup\{a,b\}$ if I don't even know what the elements of $a$ and $b$ are? Here is a picture of the exercise from the book I saw this in[image]

Comment: Seems like $\bigcup\{a,b\}=a\cup b$ to me.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought I was supposed to list the elements of a and b which seems meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

$S$ has only two elements $\{a\}$ and $\{a,b\}.$ The double union of $S$ is still $S$ itself. It is NOT $\{a,b\}$

Comment: The single union of $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ certainly is $\{a,b\}$, so why would taking the union a second time give you $S$ again?